# Can python ignore the error and return to the line next to the raised line and going on

Tags: python

Something just like that

```
try: 
    1/0
    print "hello world"
    print "every thing seems fine..."

except ZeroDivisionError: 
    print "It is not a critical error, go to next..."
    SomeWayAllowMeToExeutePrintHelloWorld_TheLineNextToTheRaisedLine()

except: 
    print "I have no idea, just stop work..."
```

After the [1/0] raised, and [except ZeroDivisionError] catched the error, and then return to the [print "hello world"] line, and going on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Ignore Exception and Go Back to Where I Was](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817748/python-ignore-exception-and-go-back-to-where-i-was)

Comment: I want to do is hacking some other one's code. in the try: body, I will call some other's function. I can not change his function, and it just raise NOT A PROBLEM exception which it should be ingored.

Comment: So what i want is at least something done in BASIC: On error resume next

Comment: Python is not BASIC.  Your real problem is that you are relying on a function that does not fit your needs.  `On Error Resume Next` is akin to rewriting the function.  In this case the thing to do is to rewrite the function.  If you cannot do that you have no recourse.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, and there's no reason you should want to:

```
try: 
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print "It is not a critical error, go to next..."

print "hello world"
print "every thing seems fine..."
```

---

Consider this code:

```
try: 
    important_res = f(1/0)
    send_important_message(important_res)
except ZeroDivisionError: 
    print "It is not a critical error, go to next..."
    SomeWayAllowMeToExeutePrintHelloWorld_TheLineNextToTheRaisedLine()
```

If you allow execution to resume, how do you pick a value to pass to `f`?

Comment: this: send_important_message(important_res)  will raise another error, since not handlered, and not let resume next, so things go down as usual.

Comment: @truease.com: what do you mean by "handlered"? What error should it throw? What value should `important_res` hold?

Answer (score 3):

No. When an exception is raised, it always goes to the block which catches it. If you want to return to the line after the one which caused the exception, you should handle the exception immediately and then have that line below the code that handles the exception.

Answer (score 2):

No. The way to achieve what you want is to use two `try` statements:

```
try:
    try: 
        1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError: 
        print "It is not a critical error, go to next..."

    print "hello world"
    print "every thing seems fine..."
except: 
    print "I have no idea, just stop work..."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the print lines after the *try... except* statement, and use a second *try... except* statement for the second *except*.

```
try:
    try: 
        1/0

    except ZeroDivisionError: 
        print "It is not a critical error, go to next..."

except: 
    print "I have no idea, just stop work..."

print "hello world"
print "every thing seems fine..."
```

Althrough, in the second *except* case, if you just want to stop the program you should not catch the exception.

Comment: You've achieved nothing by nesting these. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18443390/102441) answer is probably what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

You can't without specifically mentioning where you want to catch the error and what doesn't need to be caught.

You can add a `finally:` code block after doing the above:

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print "error"
finally:
    print "hello world"
    print "every thing seems fine..."
```

Comment: finally does not do what OP wants, he/she only wants the prints in the normal case and the `ZeroDivisionError` case, not other ones.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage of the `try/except` clause here is to use `else` or `finally` or both, as other answers have shown.

But, you can also refactor your code so each step of the attempt is its own function, and then put it all together nicely using a loop.

Example:

```
steps = [step1, step2, step3] # pointers to function/methods

for step in steps:
    try:
        step()
    except Exception as exc:
        # handle the exception
```

---

On your code:

```
def step1():
    1/0

def step2():
    print "hello world"

def step3():
    print "every thing seems fine..."

steps = [step1, step2, step3]

for step in steps:
    try:
        step()
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print "It is not a critical error, go to next..."
    except:
        print "I have no idea, just stop work..."
```

The result:

```
>>> 
It is not a critical error, go to next...
hello world
every thing seems fine...
```

Comment: you can not split [1/0] and the 2 print lines, because maybe there are in a function. If you have a way to split a function into lines, and the lines will still work well, then you get a very good solution. I don't know gdb very well, seems it can make code run step by step. Do you have any ideas? I know what I want is not so pythonic, but python is dynamic, anything should be possible.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, You gave an example - I can only provide a solution to what you have provided us. If you have a different use-case then please show it. (At this point, better to ask a new question)